# Using BitmapFactory class in android

Tags: android

While reading this class [BitmapFactory](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html)

I noticed that almost all methods inside are static.

> Wouldn't that cause a memory exception error sooner or later?

Edit* because of another answer I am more curious of another question. Sorry for this

New question:

> Would it be good practice to reuse the same class for all activities
>   through out the entire application?.

Reason being if a bitmap is called in lazyloading where multiple threads are created there will then be a multiple instance of the BitmapFactory classes. Thus, creating multiple Bitmapfactory methods with a return of static Bitmaps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, these methods don't keep data/state whatever, it's like a box, you give input, you receive result. And that's all. The only consumed memory will be the class itself which will be done only once.

Comment: Okay makes sense the class still persist throughout the activity. So it is best practice to reuse the same class for any images you will be doing in the future correct?.

Comment: @GearsdfGearsdfas I'm not sure to understand what you say. This class is a particular case, it's more an utility class. This type of class won't "block" huge amount of memories so you can use differents ones if that was the question. For classes you instantiate or having attributes, it's a different story, be sure to understand how garbage collection is done.

Comment: I know it wont block off a huge amount but for efficiency wouldn't it be better to use only one class...Lets say multi-threading which then a random person may actually place it in there which then creates multiple classes of BitmapFactory thus wasting a lot of memory.

Comment: @GearsdfGearsdfas You shouldn't create an instance of the class to call static method. Don't use `BitmapFactory b = new BitmapFactory(); b.decodeStream(...)` but `BitmapFactory.decodeStream(...)`. I'm no expert but using multi-thread shouldn't increase the amount memory used by the Factory class itself.